# operator= in Cython cppclass

Tags: cython, cythonize

How can I tell Cython that my C++ class has overloaded `operator=`? I tried:

```
cdef extern from "my_source.H":
  cdef cppclass MyStatus:
    void operator=(const char* status)

cdef public void setStatus(MyStatus& status):
  status = "FOO"
```

but Cython either complains "Assignment to reference status" or (if I make status a non-reference) constructs a python object out of the string "FOO" and then tries to assign the python object to status.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is, that for Cython `"FOO"` is a Python-object. For expressions like

```
char *s = "FOO"
```

Cython is clever enough to understand, what you want and automatically interprets `"FOO"` as `char *`.

However, Cython doesn't really "understand"/interpret the signatures of wrapped c++-functions (for that it must be a c++-compiler) and thus cannot know, that you want `"FOO"` be a `char *`.

Thus you have to help Cython, for example:

```
status = <const char *>"FOO"
```

You also have to work around the problem with reference, for example via:

```
cdef public void setStatus(MyStatus *status):
    status[0] = <const char *>"FOO"
```

or if you want to have keep the signature of the function intact:

```
cdef public void setStatus(MyStatus& status):
     cdef MyStatus * as_ptr = &status 
     as_ptr[0] = <const char *>"FOO"
```

I'm not completely sure the problem with the assigment to reference isn't a bug.

Another observation: the assigment operators aren't part of the "official" wrap of the standard containers, see [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/bd0a2c6b34b8e7b2181fa24e9774e65fc6311edd/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd#L48) or [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/084a25f55d0b4cf8b4c3cd496ec57bb3e2f57f71/Cython/Includes/libcpp/string.pxd#L135).